# fwrite with a uint8_t array

Tags: c, int, fwrite

i'm using fwrite to write an array of type uint8_t. in the terminal, after running the program, when i use

```
cat file.txt
```

everything prints as it should be.
but when i open the file with

```
vim file.txt
```

i get a super whack file with a bunch of jibberish, mainly a high repitition of

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@...
```

vim also notes [noeol] at the bottom of the open window

context of problem: udp client/server file copy program. i need the original file to diff with my new file; which it does not.

```
uint8_t buf[...];
recvfrom(...buf...);
fwrite(buf...);
```

the original file has ~150 characters, the jibberish file has ~ 30k characters.
 i would appreciate any kind of answer or direction
-austin

Comment: Post some code, and what is in the array. Most likely you're writing a binary data and expect it to appear magically as text.

Comment: thanks! there, i added some code. im going to try converting the uint8's to chars. or to unsigned chars?

Comment: And probably you don't check that you have actually received as much as you asked for.

Comment: i do, however it got a little tricky. im receiving in packets, so the last packet might only have 1 or two useful bytes in it. i left the rest of the packet memset with '\0' characters

Comment: @austin: please post some real code. What you posted contradicts your comment (that you do check how much data you received).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When vim encounter a non-printable character in a file, it use an escape code to represent it. The `^@` escape code is used to represent the null character (i.e. `'\0'` in C). This character being non-printable, the console just discard it when you do `cat file.txt`.

So I think that your code is passing an incorrect size to the `fwrite` call. Are passing the size of the buffer instead of the size of the received data?

Your code should read something like (with proper error checking):

```
uint32_t datalen;
uint8_t buffer[BUFSIZE];
datalen = recvfrom(s, buffer, BUFSIZE, flags, &from, &from_len);
fwrite(buffer, 1, datalen, f);
```

Comment: holy crap. godsend. Sylvian Defresne is a boss. i was indeed writing with a static length of the buffersize, not realizing that recvfrom actually returns the number i need. thanks for the heads up. the entire program works amazingly